# mysql cast concat DATE column and TIME column as alias within CASE clause with 2 condition

Tags: php, mysql

In my tbl_reminders, I have 2 column date and time, I can concatenate them and cast into DATETIME format and aliased them as FULLDATETIME, but when try to use FULLDATETIME on condition in CASE clause, the query return 0 rows

The alias ALARMSTATUS is being used in androidstudio listview which toggles the switch on/off inside listview

```
$sql = "SELECT TR.PK_COL_REM_ID, TR.COL_REM_TITLE,TR.COL_REM_DESCRIPTION, TR.COL_REM_DATE, 
        TR.COL_REM_TIME,TR.COL_REM_STATUS, MA.COL_ALARM_SET_DATE,MA.COL_ALARM_SET_TIME, 
        CAST(CONCAT(TR.COL_REM_DATE,' ',TR.COL_REM_TIME) AS DATETIME) AS FULLDATETIME,
         CASE WHEN MA.COL_ALARM_USER = '".$empId."' AND FULLDATETIME >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 END AS ALARMSTATUS FROM `TBL_REMINDERS` AS TR LEFT JOIN 
        TBL_MY_ALARM AS MA ON TR.PK_COL_REM_ID = MA.FK_COL_REM_ID ORDER BY TR.COL_REM_DATE DESC";
```

[image: TBL_REMINDERS]
[image: TBL_MY_ALARM]

Comment: On a side note, you're injecting raw PHP variables into your SQL code. That not only makes your code harder to maintain but it can also be a symptom that you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Please check how to use prepared statements in your DB library documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse an alias in the SELECT clause put it in a separate SELECT with parentheses surrounded:

```
CASE WHEN MA.COL_ALARM_USER = '".$empId."' AND (SELECT FULLDATETIME) >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
END AS ALARMSTATUS
```

This works in the SELECT clause. You can not use an ALIAS in the WHERE clause.